# Rotation changes armature in rest pose

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

The character has been keyframed enough to restart the animation and I realized recently that the rotation (about 10 on the y axis) of the whole armature has been altered during those keyframes, resulting in a different T-pose when applying location and rotation (alt G + alt R).

I have parented the armature to an empty as listed in some of the questions here, and it returns to the deformed armature state. Is it necessary to preserve the default T-pose (first image)? Or just continuing the animation without solving the problem?

[image]

[image][image] [image]

Comment: yes it's better to have a correct rest pose, perpendicular to the axis. What do you mean when you say that it's parented to an empty?

Comment: I did ctrl+P by selecting the armature and a empty. When I move the empty the armature follows. The question is, if I keep all the keyframes, I can't repair the armature, and if I repair the armature, the animation is altered as it differs from the original as time goes on. See the newly added screenshot.